# Card.jsx is not properly rendering

Tags: solidity, hardhat, nextjs

I'm beginner in the field of developing Decentralized applications. Currently i'm working on a project, in which i'm developing a crowdfunding application using NextJs, HardHat, Solidity.

I'm facing an issue in which the campaign creation is successfully done, but the is not displayed below the All Listed Campaign. Here my files

index.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";

// Internal Imports
import { CrowdFundingContext } from "../Context/CrowdFunding";
import { Hero, Card, PopUp } from "../Components";

const Index = () => {
  const {
    titleData,
    getCampaigns,
    createCampaign,
    donate,
    getUserCampaigns,
    getDonations,
  } = useContext(CrowdFundingContext);

  const [allcampaign, setAllcampaign] = useState([]);
  const [usercampaign, setUsercampaign] = useState([]);
  const [openModel, setOpenModel] = useState(false);
  const [donateCampaign, setDonateCampaign] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Define an async function to fetch campaigns and user campaigns
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const allData = await getCampaigns();
        const userData = await getUserCampaigns();
        setAllcampaign(allData);
        setUsercampaign(userData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    // Call the async function to fetch data
    fetchData();
  }, [getCampaigns, getUserCampaigns]);

  console.log(donateCampaign);

  return (
    <>
      <Hero titleData={titleData} createCampaign={createCampaign} />

      <Card
        title="All Listed Campaign"
        allcampaign={allcampaign}
        setOpenModel={setOpenModel}
        setDonate={setDonateCampaign}
      />

      <Card
        title="Your Created Campaign"
        allcampaign={usercampaign}
        setOpenModel={setOpenModel}
        setDonate={setDonateCampaign}
      />

      {openModel && (
        <PopUp
          setOpenModel={setOpenModel}
          getDonations={getDonations}
          donate={donateCampaign}
          donateFunction={donate}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Card.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const Card = ({ allcampaign, setOpenModel, setDonate, title }) => {
  const daysLeft = (deadline) => {
    const difference = new Date(deadline).getTime() - Date.now();
    const remainingDays = difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
    return remainingDays.toFixed(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="px-4 py-16 mx-auto sm:max-w-xl md:max-w-full lg:max-w-screen-xl md:px-24 lg:px-8 lg:py-20">
      <p className="py-16 text-2xl font-bold leading-5">{title}</p>
      <div className="grid gap-5 lg:grid-cols-3 sm:max-w-sm sm:mx-auto lg:max-w-full">
        {allcampaign ? (
          allcampaign.length > 0 ? (
            allcampaign.map((campaign, i) => (
              <div
                onClick={() => (setDonate(campaign), setOpenModel(true))}
                key={i + 1}
                className="cursor-pointer border overflow-hidden transition-shadow duration-300 bg-white rounded"
              >
                <img
                  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/932638/pexels-photo-932638.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=3&amp;h=750&amp;w=1260"
                  className="object-cover w-full h-64 rounded"
                  alt=""
                />
                <div className="py-5 pl-2">
                  <p className="mb-2 text-xs font-semibold text-gray-600 uppercase">
                    Days Left: {daysLeft(campaign.deadline)}
                  </p>
                  <a
                    href="/"
                    aria-label="Article"
                    className="inline-block mb-3 text-black transition-colors duration-200 hover:text-deep-purple-accent-700"
                  >
                    <p className="text-2xl font-bold leading-5">
                      {campaign.title}
                    </p>
                  </a>
                  <p className="mb-4 text-gray-700">{campaign.description}</p>
                  <div className="flex space-x-4">
                    <p className="font-semibold">Target: {campaign.target} ETH</p>
                    <p className="font-semibold">
                      Raised: {campaign.amountCollected} ETH
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>No campaigns available.</p>
          )
        ) : (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

can someone help me with this?